# Limit of a two variables function

Tags: limits

I guess this is a very basic exercise, but I'm just going nowhere.

$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (1,1)} \frac{x^2 + xy - 2y^2}{x^2-y^2} $$

What I tried: Solve with directional limits over $ y=mx $ and make the substitutions. At the end I get something that depends on $m$, and therefore, limit would not exist, but according to WolframAlpha, limit should be $3/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$ \frac{x^2 + xy - 2y^2}{x^2 - y^2} = \frac{(x^2 - y^2) + y(x-y)}{x^2 - y^2} = 1 + \frac{y}{x+y}.$$

Now, it's clear that
$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (1,1)} \frac{x^2 + xy - 2y^2}{x^2 - y^2} = \lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)} \left(1 + \frac{y}{x+y}\right) = 1 + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{2}.$$

Comment: Now I see it, and it seems preety easy there. I still don't know, when I took the limit through a line $mx$ I should've got $3/2$ and not something depending on $m$, right?

Comment: No, you shouldn't get something that depends on $m$. I think the problem is that you used lines of the form $y = mx$, but you would do this if you're taking the limit to the origin. Since we're taking the limit as $(x,y) \to (1,1)$, you would want to use a line of the form $y-1 = m(x-1)$.

Answer (score 2):

By setting $x=u+1$ and $y=v+1$ the problem boils down to computing

$$ \lim_{(u,v)\to(0,0)}\frac{(u-v)(3+u+2v)}{(u-v)(u+v+2)}=\lim_{(u,v)\to(0,0)}\frac{3+u+2v}{u+v+2}=\color{red}{\frac{3}{2}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$ \displaystyle\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,1)} \frac{x^2 + xy - 2y^2}{x^2-y^2}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,1)}\frac{(x+2y)(x-y)}{(x+y)(x-y)}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,1)}\frac{x+2y}{x+y} =\frac{3}{2}$